# Any easier way to group by individual columns in Hive/Impala?

Tags: hive

I need to output report of users by their age, gender, education, income, etc from our database. However, there are about 40 variables. It seems just silly to group by each variable one bye one but I'm not aware of other ways and I don't know how to write UDF to solve it yet.  I'd appreciate your help.

It's not that complicated but it does come up a lot in daily work.  My work environment is Hive/Impala.

Answer (score 0):

**We cannot implement 'Group By' task on input rows in UDF , UDAF or UDTF.**

- UDF takes in a single input row and output a single output row.
- UDAF just does Aggregations on one column, but not by Grouping  rows.
- UDTF transforms a single input row to multiple output rows.

**Only possible solution is to write multiple Queries and Combine them using UNION ALL and display/insert into table**

Sample Query:

```
 SELECT *
    FROM
    (
        SELECT COUNT(column1),column1 FROM table GROUP BY column1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(column2),column2 FROM table GROUP BY column2
        UNION ALL
        SELECT COUNT(column3),column3 FROM table GROUP BY column3
    ) s
```